# Create image mask based on range of pixel value

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to mask my image. All the pixels having values other than

R=170-220
G=100-150
B=60-100

should be masked as black.

One can do it by looping and  finding pixel value and if it is out of range of R or G or B, then replace it with black pixel, OTHERWISE KEEP its original value, but  it cost a lot . How can I avoid if loop function. Is there any built-in function in matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Logical indexing feature of Matlab.
It allows you to index an array based on different logic statement (including logic statements based on the array element values itself).

```
Image = imread('ImageName.extension');
%Read Image

R_Channel = Image(:,:,1);
G_Channel = Image(:,:,2);
B_Channel = Image(:,:,3);
    %Isolate Colour Channels.

    %R=170-220 G=100-150 B=60-100

    %Logical Indexing
R_Channel(R_Channel < 170 | R_Channel > 220)  = 0;   %Black Mask
G_Channel(G_Channel < 100 | G_Channel > 150)  = 0;   %Black Mask
B_Channel(B_Channel < 60  | B_Channel > 100)  = 0;   %Black Mask
    %Apply constraint on each Channel

MaskedImage = cat(3,R_Channel,G_Channel,B_Channel);
    %Merge all Colour channel to get the masked Image
```

Answer (score 2):

using logical index instead. For example for `R` channel:

```
R = img(:,:,1);
R_Constraint = R >= 170 && R <= 220;
R(R_Constraint) = 1;
R(~R_Constraint) = 0;
```

Do this for `G` and `B` respectively. Then, using element-wise and to get the final result as a black-and-white image.

```
G = img(:,:,2);
G_Constraint = G >= 100 && G <= 150;
G(G_Constraint) = 1;
G(~G_Constraint) = 0;

B = img(:,:,3);
B_Constraint = B >= 60 && B <= 100;
B(B_Constraint) = 1;
B(~B_Constraint) = 0;

img = R & G & B;
img(img == 1) = 255;
img = uint8(img);
```